# make regex pattern to grab that ends with a period, one or more spaces, or the end of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, replace, regexp-replace

```py
import re

#regex pattern
time_in_numbers = r"(?:por el|entrada el|entrado el|del|)\s*(?:a[\s|]*\.[\s|]*m[\s|]*\.|a[\s|]*m[\s|]*\.|a[\s|]*\.[\s|]*m|a[\s|]*m|p[\s|]*\.[\s|]*m[\s|]*\.|p[\s|]*m[\s|]*\.|p[\s|]*\.[\s|]*m|p[\s|]*m|)"

#if it detects the regex pattern condition in the input string then it performs a replacement with the re.sub() function
input_text = re.sub(time_in_numbers, "replacement!!!", input_text)
```

Some example cases:

```py
input_text = "por el a.m.anecer"  #accept
input_text = "por el amanecer"  #not accept
input_text = "por el a.manecer" #not accept
input_text = "por el a.m anecer" #accept
input_text = "por el am anecer" #accept
input_text = "por el am.anecer" #accept
input_text = "por el a.m." #accept
input_text = "por el a.m" #accept
```

```py
input_text = input_text + "jhfsjh"
input_text = "por el a.mjhfsjh" #accept
```

I try to add `"jhfsjh"` in the end of the regex patterns, in those cases where `"am"` or `"pm"` does not end with a dot `"."` after

```py
time_in_numbers = r"(?:por el|entrada el|entrado el|del|)\s*(?:|a[\s|]*\.[\s|]*mjhfsjh|a[\s|]*mjhfsjh|p[\s|]*\.[\s|]*mjhfsjh|p[\s|]*mjhfsjh|a[\s|]*\.[\s|]*m|a[\s|]*m\s|p[\s|]*\.[\s|]*m\s|p[\s|]*m\s|)"

input_text = re.sub(time_in_numbers, "replacement!!!", input_text)

input_text = input_text.replace("jhfsjh", "") #accept
```

Is there another way for the condition to end with a period, one or more empty spaces, or the end of the string `r[\.|\s*|the end of the string]` , without doing this?

Comment: Do you have to solve the entire problem in a single line (i.e. a single regex call)?

Comment: @CarlHR At first, I wanted to know if it is possible to place it on the same line of the regex, that is, within the same pattern.
The method that I did is somewhat rustic, and perhaps it is not the most appropriate but it also works for practical purposes, if you know a better method you would help me a lot. What is sought is that in regex release complications of this type are resolved in the most direct way possible.

Comment: It's possible to make almost anything in one line of regex. But it's more complicated. It's my preference to break down the string in smaller pieces and use regex on that single piece instead of the whole string.

Comment: For example: if you know the string always starts with these characters sequences: `por el|entrada el|entrado el|del`, why not use string.startswith combined with each occurrence, and break the string in 2 parts? If this is your string: `"por el a.m.anecer"`, you could separate this in two strings: `"por el"` and `"a.m.anecer"`. Then apply regex only on the second piece: `"a.m.anecer"`.

Comment: Why do you want to allow the match a pipe-symbol?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by calling `sub`? What is the expected output?

Comment: @trincot That is to send it to a replacement function, but here I have simplified the question and the only important thing is to know if it detects it or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your current regex:

- It seems that with `[\s|]*` you want to make a space optional, but within square brackets a pipe symbol is taken as a literal character. Moreover, as you already have `*`, the space **is** already optional. So you can shorten this to just `\s*`
- By putting `|` without option at the left or right of it, you want to make the rest of the expression optional, but to achieve such there is the `?` operator. So instead of `(?:por el|entrada el|entrado el|del|)` do `(?:por el|entrada el|entrado el|del)?`.
- Your regex lists several possibilities separately, but these can be combined. For instance, you have the same options with `a` as with `p`. These can be combined by using `[ap]`.
- Your workaround to test the end of the string is not necessary. There is `$` for that purpose. But this is a case you really don't need to test separately. All you want is to make sure that the `m` is not followed by another alphanumerical character. Again there is a provision for that: use `\b`.
- As *everything* is optional in your regex, it will also match empty strings, which explains why your `sub` is resulting in so many "replacement!!!" insertions. Better make sure the regex is required to match *something* at least.

I did not quite understand what you wanted to achieve with `sub`, but as your question was about the *matching* itself, I provide here a regex with a `sub` call that will insert parentheses around the parts it matched:

```
import re

time_in_numbers = r"(por el|entrada el|entrado el|del)?\s*([ap]\s*(?:\.\s*)?m\b(?:\s*\.)?)"

tests = [
    "por el a.m.anecer",  #accept
    "por el amanecer",  #not accept
    "por el a.manecer", #not accept
    "por el a.m anecer", #accept
    "por el am anecer", #accept
    "por el am.anecer", #accept
    "por el a.m.", #accept
    "por el a.m" #accept
]

for input_text in tests:
    result = re.sub(time_in_numbers, r"(\1)(\2)", input_text)
    print (result)
```

The output of this script is:

```
(por el)(a.m.)anecer
por el amanecer
por el a.manecer
(por el)(a.m) anecer
(por el)(am) anecer
(por el)(am.)anecer
(por el)(a.m.)
(por el)(a.m)
```

The lines that have the parentheses had a match, the two other lines not.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a regex, you can use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/). By selecting the *python flavor* option, the site will match and capture strings using the python regex syntax wihtout needing to execute your python script every time.

To create this answer I've used this site. Here's the regex I got: `(?:(?:por el)|(?:entrada el)|(?:entrado el)|(?:del)|)\s+(?:(?:a *\.? *m *[\. ] *.*)|(?:a *\.? *m *[\s]))`.

By using this big string as input:

```
por el a.m.anecer
por el a.m anecer
por el am anecer
por el am.anecer
por el a.m.
por el a.m

por el amanecer
por el a.manecer
```

Only the first block is matched using the site. You can easily test it using a `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V`.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I was testing it in my code and the replacement is not done using that regex :S

Comment: Then it's because the example list you provided is incomplete. I based this answer on the `Some example cases:` list.

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez try to place all examples you can think of. Or try to explain briefly what you want to match, and what you don't want to.